# Calcular valores de una venta

Tags: python

Hola quien me puede ayudar a realizar el codigo en python de este problema, de antemano muchas gracias!! 
En un almacén que se dedica a la venta de teléfonos inteligentes se quiere conocer el IVA, el costo, y la ganancia neta de sus productos. Estos tres rubros corresponden al 19%, 61%, y 20%,
respectivamente, y se calculan sobre el valor del producto. Usted debe desarrollar un programa que permita calcular los valores requeridos por el almacén. El programa debe inicialmente solicitar dos valores, el nombre y el precio del producto. Luego, se muestran cuatro datos, el nombre, el IVA, el costo, y la ganancia neta.
Para la propuesta de solución contemple:
Proceso principal
subproceso para calcular el IVA de un producto
Subproceso para calcular el costo de un producto
Subproceso para calcular la ganancia neta del producto

ya realice uno pero no estoy seguro si es el apropiado de acuerdo a lo que me piden en el enunciado.

```
# Solicitar nombre y precio del producto al usuario

nombre_producto = input("Ingrese el nombre del producto: ")
precio_producto = float(input("Ingrese el precio del producto: "))

# Calcular el valor del IVA correspondiente al 19%
iva = precio_producto * 0.19

# Calcular el costo del producto sumando el precio y el IVA
costo_producto = precio_producto + iva

# Calcular la ganancia neta correspondiente al 20% del precio
ganancia_neta = precio_producto * 0.20

# Mostrar los resultados al usuario
print("Nombre del producto: ", nombre_producto)
print("Valor del IVA: ", iva)
print("Costo del producto: ", costo_producto)
print("Ganancia neta: ", ganancia_neta)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

en general esta bastante bien echo, excepto por 2 errores.

El costo del producto no es `precio_producto + iva`. Tal y como dice el enunciado debe ser `precio_producto * 0.61`.

Luego, te pide que sean subprocesos, es decir, que en vez de:

```
iva = precio_producto * 0.19
```

Debes crear una funcion llamada (por ejemeplo) calcular_iva() y llamarla.

Crear funcion calcular_iva:

```
def calcular_iva(precio):
    resultado = precio * 0.19
    return resultado
```

Entonces en el proceso principal, lo que haces es:

```
// En vez de
iva = precio_producto * 0.19

// haces esto:
iva = calcular_iva(precio_producto)
```

**Con lo que, con todo esto, quedaría así:**

Echa un vistazo a este codigo, es lo mismo que ya habias echo pero separando los subprocesos tal y como te piden.
Te recomiendo que lo mires, lo entiendas y lo vuelvas a escribir tu en tu compilador, si hacer un copiar pegar no aprenderás.

Un saludo

```
# Subproceso para calcular el IVA de un producto
def calcular_iva(precio):
    resultado = precio * 0.19
    return resultado

# Subproceso para calcular el costo de un producto
def calcular_costo(precio):
    resultado = precio * 0.61
    return resultado

# Subproceso para calcular la ganancia neta del producto
def calcular_ganancia_neta(precio):
    resultado = precio * 0.2
    return resultado

# Proceso principal
nombre_producto = input("Ingrese el nombre del producto: ")
precio_producto = float(input("Ingrese el precio del producto: "))

iva = calcular_iva(precio_producto)
costo = calcular_costo(precio_producto)
ganancia_neta = calcular_ganancia_neta(precio_producto)

print(f"Nombre del producto: {nombre_producto}")
print(f"IVA del producto: {iva}")
print(f"Costo del producto: {costo}")
print(f"Ganancia neta del producto: {ganancia_neta}")
```

Comment: Muy agradecido por tu explicación, hare los cambios volviendo a escribir como lo indicaste y mirare tutoriales sobre crear funciones, debo reforzar mas en esa parte. mil gracias!!!